# Program/Tool to evaluate XPath 2.0 expression

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0, xmlstarlet

xmlstarlet can be used to evaluate xpath 1.0 expressions. But it doesn't support XPath 2.0 expressions. What program/tool can be used to evaluate an XPath 2.0 expression? Something preferably written in C? Much like xmlstarlet?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Years ago I wrpte such a tool -- the XPath Visualizer 2.0. It was never published. It is written in C# (.NET). If you are interested, contact me and I will provide it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there's a real shortage of XPath 2.0 processors, especially in C. But XQuery is a superset of XPath 2.0, and there are quite a few XQuery processors around, including ones that should work in you environment. (But I'm not familiar enough to recommend one.)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [XPath 2 / XQuery 1.0 interpreter](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html). Although it is in Pascal, not in C, but you can call it on the cli like xmlstarlet, or test it on the website.

Supports everything except XML schema, but might attempt to evaluate some incorrect inputs, instead of rejecting them. (but in the default XPath 2 mode it will reject all inputs  containing XQuery expressions ). It also has some syntax extensions, like objects, pattern matching, ... (which can all be turned off)